# Replace HTML with XAML

Tags: html, xaml

Has anyone ever tried this? And I don't mean sending XAML to the browser but using XAML to build an ASP.NET control tree or something similar which then renders as HTML. XAML is intresting, HTML hasn't changed much and to my knowledge HTML5 is mostly more of the same.

Comment: Converting XAML into HTML will still use the features in HTML, and cannot include XAML features that are not supported by HTML.

Comment: how so? HTML is just an intermediate format. I'm talking about XAML on the server-side and HTML on the client-side. The framework I'm looking for would of course bridge the gap between the two. This is excatly what ASP.NET WebForms does today.

Comment: What business objective are you trying to reach, that Silverlight can't solve?

Comment: @SteveCav - None, while Silverlight is a wonderful alternative to Flash it is not the way of the standardized web. I could very well use Silverlight but in doing so I would not be using HTML, CSS and JavaScript and thus it's not a web application that runs in the browser. XAML is bigger than both WPF and Silverlight, it has other purpose outside of these frameworks.